# Geth: what does "commit new work on block" exactly mean?

Tags: go-ethereum, mining

First intuition was that it signals that there are transactions to be mined, but even without a tx on a private net sometimes I see it three times per block

```
I0604 10:00:49.877830 miner/worker.go:337]   Mined stale block (#233 / 52f98d53). 
I0604 10:00:49.898013 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 234 with 0 txs & 2 uncles. Took 357.428µs
I0604 10:00:49.909992 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 234 with 0 txs & 2 uncles. Took 334.166µs
I0604 10:00:49.960199 miner/worker.go:555] commit new work on block 234 with 0 txs & 2 uncles. Took 337.558µs
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The message **commit new work on block** is displayed by `geth` when `geth` (and `ethminer` when GPU mining) is ready to start a new set of mining computations to find a **nonce** that matches the **target**.

When a new block is found by your miner, or another miner on the Ethereum network , `geth` stops the current mining computations it is performing.

`geth` then prepares a fresh new block, built upon the block hash of the newly received block (new parent) and the following data:

- Transactions from the transaction pool to be included in the new block
- Uncle block to be included in the new block

`geth` then emits the message **commit new work on block** and starts the mining computation on this new block.

This procedure results in `geth` always mining at the top of the blockchain.

#### `commitNewWork()`

The message comes from last few lines of [Go Ethereum - miner/worker.go::`commitNewWork()`, lines  439-559](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/miner/worker.go#L439-L559):

```
func (self *worker) commitNewWork() {
    self.mu.Lock()
    defer self.mu.Unlock()
    self.uncleMu.Lock()
    defer self.uncleMu.Unlock()
    self.currentMu.Lock()
    defer self.currentMu.Unlock()

    tstart := time.Now()
    parent := self.chain.CurrentBlock()
    tstamp := tstart.Unix()
    if parent.Time().Cmp(new(big.Int).SetInt64(tstamp)) >= 0 {
        tstamp = parent.Time().Int64() + 1
    }
    // this will ensure we're not going off too far in the future
    if now := time.Now().Unix(); tstamp > now+4 {
        wait := time.Duration(tstamp-now) * time.Second
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("We are too far in the future. Waiting for", wait)
        time.Sleep(wait)
    }

    num := parent.Number()
    header := &types.Header{
        ParentHash: parent.Hash(),
        Number:     num.Add(num, common.Big1),
        Difficulty: core.CalcDifficulty(self.config, uint64(tstamp), parent.Time().Uint64(), parent.Number(), parent.Difficulty()),
        GasLimit:   core.CalcGasLimit(parent),
        GasUsed:    new(big.Int),
        Coinbase:   self.coinbase,
        Extra:      self.extra,
        Time:       big.NewInt(tstamp),
    }

    previous := self.current
    // Could potentially happen if starting to mine in an odd state.
    err := self.makeCurrent(parent, header)
    if err != nil {
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infoln("Could not create new env for mining, retrying on next block.")
        return
    }
    work := self.current

    /* //approach 1
    transactions := self.eth.TxPool().GetTransactions()
    sort.Sort(types.TxByNonce(transactions))
    */

    //approach 2
    transactions := self.eth.TxPool().GetTransactions()
    types.SortByPriceAndNonce(transactions)

    /* // approach 3
    // commit transactions for this run.
    txPerOwner := make(map[common.Address]types.Transactions)
    // Sort transactions by owner
    for _, tx := range self.eth.TxPool().GetTransactions() {
        from, _ := tx.From() // we can ignore the sender error
        txPerOwner[from] = append(txPerOwner[from], tx)
    }
    var (
        singleTxOwner types.Transactions
        multiTxOwner  types.Transactions
    )
    // Categorise transactions by
    // 1. 1 owner tx per block
    // 2. multi txs owner per block
    for _, txs := range txPerOwner {
        if len(txs) == 1 {
            singleTxOwner = append(singleTxOwner, txs[0])
        } else {
            multiTxOwner = append(multiTxOwner, txs...)
        }
    }
    sort.Sort(types.TxByPrice(singleTxOwner))
    sort.Sort(types.TxByNonce(multiTxOwner))
    transactions := append(singleTxOwner, multiTxOwner...)
    */

    work.commitTransactions(self.mux, transactions, self.gasPrice, self.chain)
    self.eth.TxPool().RemoveTransactions(work.lowGasTxs)

    // compute uncles for the new block.
    var (
        uncles    []*types.Header
        badUncles []common.Hash
    )
    for hash, uncle := range self.possibleUncles {
        if len(uncles) == 2 {
            break
        }
        if err := self.commitUncle(work, uncle.Header()); err != nil {
            if glog.V(logger.Ridiculousness) {
                glog.V(logger.Detail).Infof("Bad uncle found and will be removed (%x)\n", hash[:4])
                glog.V(logger.Detail).Infoln(uncle)
            }
            badUncles = append(badUncles, hash)
        } else {
            glog.V(logger.Debug).Infof("commiting %x as uncle\n", hash[:4])
            uncles = append(uncles, uncle.Header())
        }
    }
    for _, hash := range badUncles {
        delete(self.possibleUncles, hash)
    }

    if atomic.LoadInt32(&self.mining) == 1 {
        // commit state root after all state transitions.
        core.AccumulateRewards(work.state, header, uncles)
        header.Root = work.state.IntermediateRoot()
    }

    // create the new block whose nonce will be mined.
    work.Block = types.NewBlock(header, work.txs, uncles, work.receipts)

    // We only care about logging if we're actually mining.
    if atomic.LoadInt32(&self.mining) == 1 {
        glog.V(logger.Info).Infof("commit new work on block %v with %d txs & %d uncles. Took %v\n", work.Block.Number(), work.tcount, len(uncles), time.Since(tstart))
        self.logLocalMinedBlocks(work, previous)
    }
    self.push(work)
}
```